# Get evaluation policy on a pull request

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I'm trying to retrieve the evaluation on a pull request with the following api call:

https://dev.azure.com///_apis/policy/evaluations?artifactId=vstfs:///Git/PullRequestId/71aa4bb3-8b6c-404e-a0ed-a450a41bc297/56036600-b23c-4de6-a97d-a760749e3088/102388&api-version=7.1-preview.1

I can see the pull request and the evaluation steps when navigating in azure devops, but when I try to access it via the API I get the following error:

Artifact id 'vstfs:///Git/PullRequestId/71aa4bb3-8b6c-404e-a0ed-a450a41bc297%2f56036600-b23c-4de6-a97d-a760749e3088%2f102388' does not exist or you do not have permission to view it.

I should have permission because I can view it directly in the browser?

The artifactId I retrieved via the network tab for the pull request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you have been using this [API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/policy/evaluations/list?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1) but with a wrong `artifactId` in the url.

According to the document,

> Evaluations are retrieved using an artifact ID which uniquely identifies the pull request. To generate an artifact ID for a pull request, use this template:

```
vstfs:///CodeReview/CodeReviewId/{projectId}/{pullRequestId}
```

Per your scenario, please try the request below, that works for me.

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{{organization}}/71aa4bb3-8b6c-404e-a0ed-a450a41bc297/_apis/policy/evaluations?artifactId=vstfs:///CodeReview/CodeReviewId/71aa4bb3-8b6c-404e-a0ed-a450a41bc297/102388&api-version=7.1-preview.1
```